# WCF POST json object

Tags: android, json, wcf, nhibernate

I'm new on web service operations. I'm trying to create web service for my android app.Solution work for search or list operation but problem is that i can not send to object customer

These are my Models and they mapped :

```
public class Address
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }


    public virtual String City { get; set; }


    public virtual String Phone { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
   [DataMember]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual String SurName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    private IList<Address> address = new List<Address>();

    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<Address> Addresses
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }
}
```

And I try this method but it does not work

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "CreateCustomer/",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
    public Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        //Customer customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(CustomerJson);
        if(customer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("FAIL");
        }
        CustomerManager cm = new CustomerManager();
        cm.CreateCustomer(customer);

        return customer;
    }
```

And that is my Create method with Nhibernate

```
    public Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        ISession session = this.GetSession();
        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                this.GetSession().Save(customer); //new NHibernateSessionManager().GetSession();               
                this.GetSession().Save(customer.Addresses);
                tx.Commit();

            }
            catch
            {
                tx.Rollback();
            }
        }
        return customer;
    }
```

thanx for advice.

Comment: Does it throw? What's the error then?

Comment: i try that:     http://localhost:56394/Service1.svc/CreateCustomer/                                         Method not allowed ; i try                                                                                  {"Addresses":[],"Age":33,"ID":1044,"Name":"as","SurName":"Ak","address":[]}                 Server Error in '/' Application.
Stack Trace: 
[HttpA potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.

Comment: WCF is a bit heavy for your needs. I'd recommend taking a look at creating Web API app to service your application.

Comment: `localhost:56394` ? localhost? How would that be possible? Where is your service running? Where is your Android app running?

Comment: actuallly ,192.168.0.xx ,i just write that localhost

Comment: Why are you getting three sessions? Surely you want to use the same session?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the `CreateCustomer()` method look like this:

```
public Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    using (var session = this.GetSession())
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            session.Save(customer);
            session.Save(customer.Addresses); // This could be omitted with cascade

            tx.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            tx.Rollback();
        }
    }

    return customer;
}
```

Comment: It is work actually but i decide to change my opinion .I will try POST operation on Test Console app. I think , when using POST operation  writing data to url with Json  not good idea. Thnx for help.